# IE8 not taking absolutely positioned element out of flow

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, position, overflow, zurb-foundation

so I've encountered a bug that I can't figure out in IE8. I've seen some doozies, but this one might take the cake.

I tried replicating it in Codepen, but we have a lot of code for this so I'll try including the computed styles from IE8.

Using Foundation 5, I have a Top Bar that starts out looking like this:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

The dropdown is positioned absolutely, so it obviously shouldn't be stretching out the parent container. It doesn't actually stretch out the parent, but the grandparent. Here's the markup:

```
<nav id="global-nav" class="top-bar has-dropdown show-for-large-up" data-topbar >
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <a href="">Title</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>

    <section class="links top-bar-section">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="">Create</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a>Explore</a>
                <ul class="dropdown tab-left" id="explore-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Find</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-form search">
          <form id="header_search" name="search_form">
              <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="search" results=3 id="search_term" name="search_value" maxlength="200" />
              <button id="search_submit"></button>
          </form>
      </li>

      <li class="login">
          <a href="javascript:;" id="launch-login">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

The computed CSS from IE8:

```
#global-nav{ //this is the topbar that is stretching
    background: #2a2d43;
    background-image: none;
    color: #666;
    display: block !important;
    font: inherit;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    width: 100%;
}

li.has-dropdown .dropdown{
    background: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    z-index: 99;
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    font: inherit;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto !important;
    left: 10%;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: auto;
    top: 64px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: auto;
}

li.has-dropdown.hover .dropdown{ //the open dropdown state
    clip: rect(auto auto auto auto);
    visibility: visible;
}
```

If you need more information let me know. Thanks in advance.

For reference, I'm testing on a Parallels VM of Win7 with IE8, using IE8 document mode and IE8 Standards.

Comment: IE8 isn't supported in  foundation 5 at all http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compatibility.html  and has only partial support in F4 http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/support.html if you want full IE8 support use F3. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation+internet-explorer-8

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I've solved most of the things that didn't work. This is a very specific question about a very specific problem.

Comment: I saw some attempt to make F5 IE8 compatible without the JS part like this one http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/241-foundation-5-and-ie8 but it's not clear how reliable this solution is and it's hard to determine whether you have solved most of them or just some.

Comment: I know all that, the problem isn't Foundation, it is very specifically a problem with CSS and IE8. I do not need help with Foundation, I need help with this dropdown menu not being taken out of the flow.

Comment: Your html `<nav id="global-nav"` and your css `#nav-global`. See the difference?

Comment: Yeah, that was just a typo here, not in my code. But thanks

Comment: Given the `clip` property only work if positioning is absolute, maybe IE8 is treating the drop-down "specially". I wonder if using a different style to control visibility (like `display`) would have any effect?

Comment: does this kind of CSS comment not a probleme ? `//the open dropdown state` it should be more alike `/*the open dropdown state*/`

Comment: this might be obvious, and silly, but does foundation do something like `document.createElement("nav");` to make `nav` tags available in IE8?

Comment: So far, there hasn't been one IE8 problem that I haven't been able to solve, but I would still need your original code. The computed style won't do, because that might be erroneous due to coding or IE8 implementation errors. Preferably a whole-page but bare-bones code, since Fiddle and the likes are dysfunctional in IE8.

Comment: @FrankConijn I can't show the link publicly but if you want to hit me up privately I can show you. calley.nye@gmail.com

Comment: I don't mind private emails, but as you wrote "I tried replicating it in Codepen, but we have a lot of code for this", finding a solution in vivo with the limited Development function (the real) IE8 has, sounds like a lot of work... Maybe you wanna give Codepen another try? And I have another question: I am not seeing a `:hover` declaration in your ÇSS? Does that mean that the hover state is Javascript-driven?

Comment: It is not an IE8 problem. See my answer.

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that you're using 'visibility' to show/hide rather than 'display'. Obvs I can't test that in your environment, but that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to view this?  I am wondering if maybe you should set the ul to position relative.  I think the li is falling back to the first relatively positioned item.  Hopes this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't. Even if it was falling back to the first relatively positioned item, it still shouldn't stay in the flow.

Comment: Do you have a link to view this?

Answer (score 0):

If any of the parent elements of the absolute element has position: relative then the absolute  is computed relative to that,

try removing the position: relative from the parent containers maybe it could help

also make sure you have correct

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the beginning of your file

Comment: No matter what element has position:relative on it, it shouldn't be expanding a containing element. position:absolute is supposed to take the element out of the flow, so its parent should not be expanding, regardless of which element its positioned to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an IE8 rendering error, but a coding error/incompatibility somewhere. This demo code shows that IE8 does take absolutely positioned drop-down elements out of the flow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Demo IE8 Drop-Down Menu</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#navDivParent { /* = grandparent of the dropdown menu */
    background-color: darkblue;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    width: 550px;
}
#navDiv ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#navDiv ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#navDiv ul li ul li {
    clear: left;
}
#navDiv ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#navDiv ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#navDiv a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: yellow;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navDiv #item2SubList a {
    width: 175px;
}
#navDiv a:hover {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navDivParent">This is the grandparent<br> of the dropdown menu.
        <div id="navDiv">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item w/ child</a>
                    <ul id="item2SubList">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu sub-item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu sub-item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu sub-item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

.
I haven't made a live demo because JSFiddle, JSBin and the likes don't function in IE8, but I tested it in both a real IE8 and IE9 in IE8 mode.

As the in the question provided code does not contain a CSS `:hover` state declaration, the coding error/incompatibility might lie in the Javascript that would drive the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown has a max-width of 200px. IE8 doesn't deal well with max-width. Essentially it's treated as a width declaration. Your forcing a width of 200px in IE8. You would need to set it to none...

```
max-width:none\9; /* IE8 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this "bug" has anything to do with the position: absolute; not taking the .dropdown out of the flow. li.has-dropdown also has a .hover state applied to it. There is likely some other styling applied to li.has-dropdown that is causing #global-nav to shift. Perhaps some extra padding is being applied to li.has-dropdown. Unfortunately we don't have all the code to properly debug this.